# How to write nested loop in ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How can I rewrite this nested loop in ES6 and have it in one line ?

```js
const fruits = [ { id: 1, name: "orange"},{ id: 3, name: "apple"},{ id: 4, name: "grape"}]
const selectedFruits = [ "2", "3" ]
  
let fruitsArr= [];

fruits.forEach(fruit => {
  selectedFruits.forEach(selected => {
    if (selected == fruit.id) {
      fruitsArr.push(fruit.name)
    }
  })
})

console.log(fruitsArr)
```

Comment: That **is** ES6, and putting it on one line would just make it harder to read.

Comment: *Any* Javascript code can be squashed onto one line

Comment: Just a logic problem. `let fruitsArr = fruits.filter(f => selectedFruits.indexOf(f.id + "") > 0).map(f => f.name);`

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array and check with `includes` by changing `selectedFruits` to an array of number.

```js
const
    fruits = [{ id: 1, name: "orange" }, { id: 3, name: "apple" }, { id: 4, name: "grape" }],
    selectedFruits = [2, 3],
    fruitsArr = fruits.filter(({ id }) => selectedFruits.includes(id));

console.log(fruitsArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `reduce`:

```js
const fruits = [ { id: 1, name: "orange"},{ id: 3, name: "apple"},{ id: 4, name: "grape"}]
const selectedFruits = [ "2", "3" ]
const fruitsArr = fruits.reduce((p, c) => (selectedFruits.includes(String(c.id)) && p.push(c), p), [])
console.log(fruitsArr)
```